# how to plot arrow on date xaxis?

Tags: charts, plot, gnuplot

I have plot that has dates for xaxis. The format is

```
set xdata time
set timefmt x "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"
```

The actual data file has "date" only timestamps - i.e. not the following T part BUT plots correctly.

```
20130601
```

When I want to plot a vertical arrow I get no error - but no arrow either:

```
set arrow from 20130601,0 to 20130601,500000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using time formats, the respective parts of the data file are read in as string. So for the arrow you must use

```
set arrow from "20130601",graph 0 to "20130601",graph 1
```

If you use integers, then they are interpreted as Unix timestamps, and 20130601 corresponds the the 21. August 1970. So you don't get an error, but the date is not in your range.

Comment: OK I see - is that in the documentation somewhere? I did not see that

Comment: Yes, see the section "Coordinates": "If one (or more) axis is timeseries, the appropriate coordinate should be given as a quoted time string according to the timefmt format string."